# How to set the default connection charset for SqlAnywhere 11 Windows network server?

Tags: character-encoding, sybase, sqlanywhere

I have an application that doesn't have the connection charset defined in its JDBC connection string to SqlAnywhere 11 network server in a Windows environament.

Since I cannot change the application is there any way to set the default client connection charset in server settings?
I found the environament variable "SACHARSET" in documentation, I tried to set

```
SACHARSET = UTF8
```

But it did not help.

Do yuo know how to set the default charset for client connection in Sybase SQL Anywhere 11 server?